# Serve a static website on S3 via CloudFront and ACM SSL without Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-acm

There is a great write-up of what I consider a "standard" setup of a single-page app hosted on AWS: [S3 Static Sites](https://gist.github.com/bradwestfall/b5b0e450015dbc9b4e56e5f398df48ff). It includes

- Deployment to S3
- SSL certificate via ACM
- Distribution via CloudFront
- DNS configuration in Route53

The site we are working on, however, is set up for a customer who does not use Route53. How do I tell them to configure the DNS records? It should be waterproof, so I want to check here with experiences from other users.

Given:

- Cloudfront domain name: `d12ab345cd6ef.cloudfront.net`
- S3 bucket: `spa.example.com`

Is it just a CNAME record?

```
spa.example.com. CNAME d12ab345cd6ef.cloudfront.net
```

Does that work? Is there an instance where this does not work? The setup does not use a naked domain.

Going through the domains set up with an A record and the *Alias* flag on Route53 pointing to the CloudFormation distribution, as described in the article linked above ([section Route53](https://gist.github.com/bradwestfall/b5b0e450015dbc9b4e56e5f398df48ff#route-53)), I see the following

```
$ dig working.foo.com
...
working.foo.com. 28 IN  A   54.230.44.111
working.foo.com. 28 IN  A   54.230.44.112
working.foo.com. 28 IN  A   54.230.44.113
working.foo.com. 28 IN  A   54.230.44.114
...
```

Comment: Yes, a CNAME will work, as long as you've put that domain/subdomain in the CloudFront distribution's settings so AWS knows where to point it.

Comment: @ceejayoz Great. Thank you! Could put this in an answer and I can remove this answer part from my question? This would make it easier for someone else to extract that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a subdomain like `spa.example.com`, a `CNAME` is all you need. Set up the record, then [tell CloudFront about it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#CreatingCNAME) in the distribution's settings, and you're good to go.

For an apex domain, Route 53 makes things a lot easier (via `ALIAS` records), but some other DNS providers (off the top of my head: [DNSMadeEasy](https://dnsmadeeasy.com/services/anamerecords/) and [CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root)) offer a similar thing that'll work fine with CloudFront.